# cap locks on xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, xcode6

Hey I'm making a custom keyboard in Xcode 6 and i want to add more letters or perhaps  connect another view to the main view;just like caps so when you press caps i can add more letters. Its a keyboard in another language and not all characters fit in the main view. is there a way i can add more characters.

Also is there a way to add constraints to the keyboard becuase i tried the add or missing constraint method and when it opens in the simulator the letters with the constraint go missing
Thank you